# Accessing a web site via web scrape

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

When attempting to web scrape [Rubies](http://www.rubies.com), I am unable to get past the login. I have absolutely no idea why I am not able to, but here are the cURL options that I am using. If anyone sees a problem, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.rubies.com/customer/account/loginPost/",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('form_key' => "****", "login[username]" => "****", "login[password]" => "****", "persistent_remember_me" => 'on', "send" => ''),
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Host: www.rubies.com',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Origin: https://www.rubies.com',
        'Referer: https://www.rubies.com/customer/account/',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
    ),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true
));
```

I currently have the form key hard encoded, but I am not sure if I would have to change the form key depending on the login. The response from the post is empty, but I get redirected 2 times. Once to the account page, then back to the login. If anyone can tell me what is going on, then I would appreciate it. I think they are using some kind of basic auth system.

Answer (score 1):

Use fiddler2 or another packet sniffer to look at the cURL traffic both requests and responses. Compare that to the traffic using a browser.

You probably either missed or mistyped a field, or missed follow-up steps like setting cookies and posting additional data.

Code for a login often requires fetching the login page, scraping a one-time token (changes with each page request), then posting as the first step.  This might trigger script code to set cookies and/or automatically submit other data.

Comment: actually, regarding websites, in my experience, 99% of the time, chrome's dev-tools's Network tab is sufficient :) (and when it isn't, as you say, Fiddler)

Comment: Agreed, I mostly use Chrome's F12 first for browser traffic since it's much easier to read.  But that won't show you the cURL version of the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

you do several mistakes.

you say to the server that your POST body is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded, but you give `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` an array, so what you *actually* send to the server, is `multipart/form-data` encoded. to have curl send the post data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, urlencode the data for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` - with arrays specifically, http_build_query will do this for you. furthermore, with POSTs when doing `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, don't set the content-type header at all, curl will do it for you, automatically, depending on which encoding was used. on that note, you shouldn't set the `User-Agent` header manually, either, but use `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`. and you should not set the `Host` header either, curl generates that automatically, and you're more likely than curl to make a mistake.
also, here you send a fake `Referer` header, some websites can detect when the referer is fake, it's safer just to set `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER`, and make a real request, thus obtaining a real referer. also, to actually login to `https://www.rubies.com/customer/account/loginPost/` , you need both a cookie session, and a `form_key` code, the `form_key` is probably tied to your cookie session, and probably a form of CSRF token, but you provide no code to acquire either. and on top of that, you may need a real `referer`.

using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php , 
here's an example code i *think* would be able to log in, with a real username/password, doing none of the mistakes i listed above:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ();

$hc->_setComfortableOptions ();
$hc->exec ( 'https://www.rubies.com/customer/account/login/' ); // << getting a referer, form_key (csrf token?), and a session.
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $hc->getResponseBody () );
$csrf = NULL;

// extract the form_key
foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "form" ) as $form ) {
    if ($form->getAttribute ( "class" ) !== 'form form-login') {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ( $form->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
        if ($input->getAttribute ( "name" ) !== 'form_key') {
            continue;
        }
        $csrf = $input->getAttribute ( "value" );
        break;
    }
    break;
}
if ($csrf === NULL) {
    throw new \RuntimeException ( 'failed to extract the form_key token!' );
}

$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                'form_key' => $csrf,
                'login' => array (
                        'username' => '???',
                        'password' => '???' 
                ),
                'persistent_remember_me' => 'on',
                'send' => ''  // ??
        ) ) 
) );

$hc->exec ( 'https://www.rubies.com/customer/account/login/' );
hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getResponseBody () );
```

EDIT: fixed an url, the original code definitely wouldn't work, but it should now.